# Dynamically sum numbers in separate sheet by unique ID

Tags: excel, excel-2007, spreadsheet, excel-formula

I'm putting together an excel workbook for a friend to track his expenses and profit from selling cars. The workbook has 2 sheets (Cars, Expenses).

The cars sheet looks like this:

```
      A       B      C       D      E        F           G        H
1] Stock# | Year | Make | Model | Cost | Expenses | Sell Price | Profit
2] 1      | 2001 | Ford | Blah  | 1500 | 450      | 3000       | 1050
3] 2      | 2012 | Ford | Meh   | 1600 | 250      | 3500       | 1650
```

The expenses sheet looks like this:

```
     A             B          C
1] Stock # |     Item     | Cost
2] 1       | Brakes       | 200
3] 1       | Paint        | 200
4] 1       | Bumper Fluid |  50
5] 2       | Exhaust      | 250
```

Currently in the Cars sheet, I have the Expenses summing manually selected cells from the Expenses sheet " =SUM(Expenses!C2:C4) ". Would there be anyway to automate it so that instead of looking for manually selected cells, it would look for cells via the unique Stock # / ID?

Comment: As an excel formula this is better asked on superuser rather than stackoverflow which is intended for programming questions

Comment: @brettdj Since the start, SO has accept Excel formula questions.

Comment: @Remou that's interesting as I have had a number of non-VBA solutions moved to SU (at least 3), and I have seen numerous comments (and Close comments) from others indicating that formula only solutions don't belong here. [Recent sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589359/excel-last-non-empty-cell-of-a-column)

Comment: @brettdj Yep. It is all a bit fuzzy. I have seen it go both ways, but SO is riddled with Excel formula solutions.

Comment: @remou This is all pretty confusing, [similar discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8608976/641067) :) It is similar to the very grey "do we allow full/partial/no password breaking on Excel files" debate that I have seen played out on a number of forums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A5, 1, C2:C5)
```

This will return 450, or the sum of all Stock# 1

```
=SUMIF(A2:A5, 2, C2:C5)
```

This will return 250, or the sum of all Stock# 2

Comment: right approach but should take into account the off-sheet lookup, ie `=SUMIF(expenses!$A$1:$A$100,A2,expenses!$C$1:$C$100)` does this plus sets up absolute ranges so that summaries can easily be created for A3 (stock value of '2') etc

Comment: @brettdj Why not use "open-end" ranges? e.g. `=SUMIF(Expenses!A$2:A, A2, Expenses!C$2:C)`

Comment: It would be better to convert to a table and reference the entire field, ie =SUMIF(Expenses!Table1[Stock#], A2, Expenses!Table1[Cost])

Comment: Thank you guys, all of your comments were very helpful!

Comment: @hgabrey its a personal preference but IMHO ranges should be fit for purpose, using entire columns/rows risks incorporating unwanted data, plus its a step towards using unncessary formulae

Comment: @hgabrey, I totally agree with brettdj that ranges should be specific, especially on a sumif of simple imputs.  By pulling the entire column, you could easily end up summing up a date field, a field heading or some other values into your sums.  Keep it tidy IMO.  Having said that, I'll often use the entire field for a quick fx that i'm about to delete after.

Answer (score 0):

Sumif is what you are looking for.  F1 in Excel and search for 'sumif' or hit the f(x) button next to your formula bar to que up the formula help.

Either way, in help you should find a working example to paste into excel.

Sumif will change your life in excel.